# Why would _exit fail?

Tags: c, abort

I was looking for the source code of the `abort()` function in C, and I came across this:

[`abort.c`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/abort.c.html):

```
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.
   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */
#include <libc-lock.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sigsetops.h>
/* Try to get a machine dependent instruction which will make the
   program crash.  This is used in case everything else fails.  */
#include <abort-instr.h>
#ifndef ABORT_INSTRUCTION
/* No such instruction is available.  */
# define ABORT_INSTRUCTION
#endif
/* Exported variable to locate abort message in core files etc.  */
struct abort_msg_s *__abort_msg __attribute__ ((nocommon));
libc_hidden_def (__abort_msg)
/* We must avoid to run in circles.  Therefore we remember how far we
   already got.  */
static int stage;
/* We should be prepared for multiple threads trying to run abort.  */
__libc_lock_define_initialized_recursive (static, lock);
/* Cause an abnormal program termination with core-dump.  */
void
abort (void)
{
  struct sigaction act;
  sigset_t sigs;
  /* First acquire the lock.  */
  __libc_lock_lock_recursive (lock);
  /* Now it's for sure we are alone.  But recursive calls are possible.  */
  /* Unblock SIGABRT.  */
  if (stage == 0)
    {
      ++stage;
      __sigemptyset (&sigs);
      __sigaddset (&sigs, SIGABRT);
      __sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigs, 0);
    }
  /* Send signal which possibly calls a user handler.  */
  if (stage == 1)
    {
      /* This stage is special: we must allow repeated calls of
         `abort' when a user defined handler for SIGABRT is installed.
         This is risky since the `raise' implementation might also
         fail but I don't see another possibility.  */
      int save_stage = stage;
      stage = 0;
      __libc_lock_unlock_recursive (lock);
      raise (SIGABRT);
      __libc_lock_lock_recursive (lock);
      stage = save_stage + 1;
    }
  /* There was a handler installed.  Now remove it.  */
  if (stage == 2)
    {
      ++stage;
      memset (&act, '\0', sizeof (struct sigaction));
      act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
      __sigfillset (&act.sa_mask);
      act.sa_flags = 0;
      __sigaction (SIGABRT, &act, NULL);
    }
  /* Try again.  */
  if (stage == 3)
    {
      ++stage;
      raise (SIGABRT);
    }
  /* Now try to abort using the system specific command.  */
  if (stage == 4)
    {
      ++stage;
      ABORT_INSTRUCTION;
    }
  /* If we can't signal ourselves and the abort instruction failed, exit.  */
  if (stage == 5)
    {
      ++stage;
      _exit (127);
    }
  /* If even this fails try to use the provided instruction to crash
     or otherwise make sure we never return.  */
  while (1)
    /* Try for ever and ever.  */
    ABORT_INSTRUCTION;
}
libc_hidden_def (abort)
```

Looking through, I saw this and got very confused:

After `_exit` is called there is:

> If even this fails try to use the provided instruction to crash
> or otherwise make sure we never return.

Why would `_exit` fail? `_exit` is never return and terminates the program. Why on Earth would `_exit` be unable to terminate the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes `abort()` is called in situations where memory has become corrupted.  This could potentially cause `_exit()` to fail somehow.

Or there could be a bug in the OS that prevents `_exit()` from working.

Or the program was linked with a library that replaces `_exit()`.

All these things are very unlikely (and in the case of memory corruption, it could just as easily cause `abort()` itself to fail), but `abort()` is trying to cover all bases.

Comment: By memory corruption, could the code for `_exit` have been accidentally overridden?

Comment: Normally code is in read-only memory, so it's unlikely. But the stack could be munged.

Comment: @user16217248 some people would call it defensive programming, for others it is borderline paranoia.

Comment: @SergeyA I guess I am going with the second one then

Answer (score 1):

On many systems, there will be some code running which isn't in a "process" per se.  As a simple example, the code that is responsible for performing task switching among processes will often not be able to run in the old nor new process, but rather in a context that isn't associated with either.  Although only a small number of system functions should be called within such contexts, and neither `exit()` nor `abort()` is among them, the fact that something shouldn't happen is no guarantee that it won't.  Situations may sometimes arise where all courses of action are expected to be bad, but calling `abort` may be seen as the least bad among them.

If `exit()` is called when code is in a context not associated with any identifiable process, it won't be able to carry out its normal duties.  Its caller isn't likely going to be prepared for the possibility that it might return, so its most logical course of action may be to call `abort()`.  On the other hand, since the most natural course of action for `abort()` would be to call `exit()` to clean up the current process, this creates a deadly recursive mutual dependency.  To accommodate that, the `abort` function has a dedicated static object which is used to determine if it gets invoked recursively and, if so, attempt different means of forcing the program to exit.  It's likely that the `exit()` function also employs similar measures so that if some cleanup action triggers an `abort()` which then calls `exit()`, it will be able to try performing whatever portions of the cleanup would have followed the part that failed.

Note that if normal means of aborting fail, having an abort function enter an endless loop with a dummy side effect may be just as good as any other course of action, but in some cases an endless loop that repeatedly tries to execute ABORT_INSTRUCTION may be better, since other supervisory subsystems may be able to recognize when an execution context has become stuck in a loop that does nothing other than ABORT_INSTRUCTION and take appropriate action (e.g. forcing a system restart, depending upon what the crashed code had been doing).

Comment: Are you hypothesizing or do have a particular system in mind where `_exit` called outside of process context will return?

Comment: @SergeyA: Much of the design of this code isn't there to deal with the possibility that `exit` might return, but rather that it might recursively call `abort`.  On the other hand, if `exit` calls `abort` which in turn calls `exit`, having `exit` return would guard against the possibility that recursive invocations would blow the stack.  It wouldn't be possible to design an `exit` that could work sensibly with all plausible reasonable versions of `abort`, nor vice versa, but it's possible to design the functions to be compatible with many possible variations of each other.